# Using a function inside another function doesn't work: variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, function, sprite

We are coding a game with JavaScript. We are almost there. The only thing is the realising the last loop. We want to do this with a function. If we start a function in this loop we get an error. If we skip the first function, the following function gives an error.

The function can be seen below in the code, see `function levelUp()`. If we delete this code it works.

- In a test-file works it. We can start a function in a function.
- Read many fora for solutions. But none worked.

Now the screen stays blank. And console-log gives errors:

> ```
> (index):341 Uncaught ReferenceError: coordinaten is not defined
> at droidsNeerzetten ((index):341)
> at levelUp ((index):83)
> at (index):65
> ```

We expected 9 sprites to appear so the game can start.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Hyperman: Hoelang blijf jij uit de handen van de droids?</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>    
    <body>
        <div class="kader">
            <div class="titel">
                <img src="hyperman_tekst.png" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="ranglijst">
                <div class="links">#1 Jeroen</div><div class="rechts">1234pt.</div><br />
                <div class="links">#2 Jeroen</div><div class="rechts">1234pt.</div><br />
                <div class="links">#3 Jeroen</div><div class="rechts">1234pt.</div><br />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="spel-data">
                <div class="links">Level:</div><div class="rechts"><span id="level">0</span></div><br />
                <div class="links">Punten:</div><div class="rechts"><span id="score">0</span></div><br />
                <div class="links">Leven(s):</div><div class="rechts">2</div><br />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="knoppen">
                <button class="knop" onclick="LB()"><img src="pijl_linksboven.png" /></button>
                <button class="knop knop-rechts" onclick="MB()"><img src="pijl_middenboven.png" /></button>
                <button class="knop knop-rechts" onclick="RB()"><img src="pijl_rechtsboven.png" /></button>
                <br />
                <button class="knop" onclick="LM()"><img src="pijl_linksmidden.png" /></button>
                <button class="knop knop-rechts" onclick="MM()"><img src="pijl_middenmidden.png" /></button>
                <button class="knop knop-rechts" onclick="RM()"><img src="pijl_rechtsmidden.png" /></button>
                <br />
                <button class="knop" onclick="LO()"><img src="pijl_linksonder.png" /></button>
                <button class="knop knop-rechts" onclick="MO()"><img src="pijl_middenonder.png" /></button>
                <button class="knop knop-rechts" onclick="RO()"><img src="pijl_rechtsonder.png" /></button>
                <br />
                <button class="brede-knop" onclick="randomHyperman()">HyperJump</button>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="info">
                <a href="https://www.jeroenvanrensen.nl/hyperman/info.html" target="_blank"><img src="info.png" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // CONSTANTEN
                var CANVAS_HOOGTE = 620;
                var CANVAS_BREEDTE = 740;
                var COORDINATEN_X = [0,20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200,220,240,260,280,300,320,340,360,380,400,420,440,460,480,500,520,540,560,580,600,620,640,660,680,700,720];
                var AANTAL_X_COORDINATEN = 37;
                var COORDINATEN_Y = [0,20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200,220,240,260,280,300,320,340,360,380,400,420,440,460,480,500,520,540,560,580,600];
                var AANTAL_Y_COORDINATEN = 31;
                var STAP_GROOTTE = 20;

            // START
                // Canvas aanmaken
                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
                canvas.width = CANVAS_BREEDTE;
                canvas.height = CANVAS_HOOGTE;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                var level = 1;
                var punten = 0;

                levelUp();

                function levelUp() {
                    // Hyperman positioneren
                    // Eerste getal (0, 1 of 2) = wezen (Hyperman, Droid of Hoopje); Tweede getal is het nummer (0 = ALTIJD Hyperman); Derde getal is X-coordinaat; Vierde getal is Y-coordinaat
                    var coordinaten = [[0,0,0,0]];
                    document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = level;
                    var droids = ((level * 4) + 4) + 1;
                    for(var i=1;i<droids;i++) {
                        coordinaten[i] = [1,i,0,0];
                    }
                    console.log(coordinaten[1][1]);
                    coordinaten[0][2] = COORDINATEN_X[Math.floor((Math.random())*AANTAL_X_COORDINATEN)];
                    coordinaten[0][3] = COORDINATEN_Y[Math.floor((Math.random())*AANTAL_Y_COORDINATEN)];
                    // randomHypermanPositie();

                    var spelerMagZetten = true;

                    droidsNeerzetten();
                    hoofdlus();
                }

            // HOOFDLUS
                function hoofdlus() {
                    draw();
                    update();
                    botstEenDroid();
                    window.requestAnimationFrame(hoofdlus);
                }

            // HYPERMAN-BESTURING
                window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
                function onKeyDown(event) {
                    if(event.keyCode == 48) {
                        randomHyperman();
                    }
                    if(event.keyCode == 72) {
                        randomHyperman();
                    }
                    if(event.keyCode == 49) {
                        LO();
                    }
                    if(event.keyCode == 50) {
                        MO();
                    }
                    if(event.keyCode == 51) {
                        RO();
                    }
                    if(event.keyCode == 52) {
                        LM();
                    }
                    if(event.keyCode == 53) {
                        MM();
                    }
                    if(event.keyCode == 54) {
                        RM();
                    }
                    if(event.keyCode == 55) {
                        LB();
                    }
                    if(event.keyCode == 56) {
                        MB();
                    }
                    if(event.keyCode == 57) {
                        RB();
                    }
                }
                function LB () {
                    if (spelerMagZetten) {
                        coordinaten[0][2] = coordinaten[0][2] - STAP_GROOTTE;
                        coordinaten[0][3] = coordinaten[0][3] - STAP_GROOTTE;
                        XYControle();
                        hoopjeControle(1);
                        spelerMagZetten = false;
                    }
                }
                function MB () {
                    if (spelerMagZetten) {
                        coordinaten[0][2] = coordinaten[0][2] + 0;
                        coordinaten[0][3] = coordinaten[0][3] - STAP_GROOTTE;
                        XYControle();
                        hoopjeControle(2);
                        spelerMagZetten = false;
                    }
                }
                function RB () {
                    if (spelerMagZetten) {
                        coordinaten[0][2] = coordinaten[0][2] + STAP_GROOTTE;
                        coordinaten[0][3] = coordinaten[0][3] - STAP_GROOTTE;
                        XYControle();
                        hoopjeControle(3);
                        spelerMagZetten = false;
                    }
                }
                function LM () {
                    if (spelerMagZetten) {
                        coordinaten[0][2] = coordinaten[0][2] - STAP_GROOTTE;
                        coordinaten[0][3] = coordinaten[0][3] + 0;
                        XYControle();
                        hoopjeControle(4);
                        spelerMagZetten = false;
                    }
                }
                function MM () {
                    if (spelerMagZetten) {
                        coordinaten[0][2] = coordinaten[0][2] + 0;
                        coordinaten[0][3] = coordinaten[0][3] + 0;
                        XYControle();
                        hoopjeControle(5);
                        spelerMagZetten = false;
                    }
                }
                function RM () {
                    if (spelerMagZetten) {
                        coordinaten[0][2] = coordinaten[0][2] + STAP_GROOTTE;
                        coordinaten[0][3] = coordinaten[0][3] + 0;
                        XYControle();
                        hoopjeControle(6);
                        spelerMagZetten = false;
                    }
                }
                function LO () {
                    if (spelerMagZetten) {
                        coordinaten[0][2] = coordinaten[0][2] - STAP_GROOTTE;
                        coordinaten[0][3] = coordinaten[0][3] + STAP_GROOTTE;
                        XYControle();
                        hoopjeControle(7);
                        spelerMagZetten = false;
                    }
                }
                function MO () {
                    if (spelerMagZetten) {
                        coordinaten[0][2] = coordinaten[0][2] + 0;
                        coordinaten[0][3] = coordinaten[0][3] + STAP_GROOTTE;
                        XYControle();
                        hoopjeControle(8);
                        spelerMagZetten = false;
                    }
                }
                function RO () {
                    if (spelerMagZetten) {
                        coordinaten[0][2] = coordinaten[0][2] + STAP_GROOTTE;
                        coordinaten[0][3] = coordinaten[0][3] + STAP_GROOTTE;
                        XYControle();
                        hoopjeControle(9);
                        spelerMagZetten = false;
                    }
                }
                function XYControle() {
                    for(var i=0;i<coordinaten.length;i++) {
                        console.log('ID: ',coordinaten[i][1]);
                        console.log('Spritesoort: ',coordinaten[i][0]);
                        console.log('-----');
                    }
                    console.log('---------------------------------------------------------------------');

                    if (coordinaten[0][2] < 0) {
                        coordinaten[0][2] = coordinaten[0][2] + STAP_GROOTTE;
                    }
                    if (coordinaten[0][2] > (CANVAS_BREEDTE - STAP_GROOTTE)) {
                        coordinaten[0][2] = coordinaten[0][2] - STAP_GROOTTE;
                    }
                    if (coordinaten[0][3] < 0) {
                        coordinaten[0][3] = coordinaten[0][3] + STAP_GROOTTE;
                    }
                    if (coordinaten[0][3] > (CANVAS_HOOGTE - STAP_GROOTTE)) {
                        coordinaten[0][3] = coordinaten[0][3] - STAP_GROOTTE;
                    }
                }
                function hoopjeControle(richting) {
                    for(var i=0;i<coordinaten.length;i++) {
                        if(coordinaten[i][0] == 2) {
                            if(coordinaten[0][2] == coordinaten[i][2] && coordinaten[0][3] == coordinaten[i][3]) {
                                if(richting == 1) {
                                    coordinaten[0][2] = coordinaten[0][2] + STAP_GROOTTE;
                                    coordinaten[0][3] = coordinaten[0][3] + STAP_GROOTTE;
                                }
                                if(richting == 2) {
                                    coordinaten[0][2] = coordinaten[0][2] + 0;
                                    coordinaten[0][3] = coordinaten[0][3] + STAP_GROOTTE;
                                }
                                if(richting == 3) {
                                    coordinaten[0][2] = coordinaten[0][2] - STAP_GROOTTE;
                                    coordinaten[0][3] = coordinaten[0][3] + STAP_GROOTTE;
                                }
                                if(richting == 4) {
                                    coordinaten[0][2] = coordinaten[0][2] + STAP_GROOTTE;
                                    coordinaten[0][3] = coordinaten[0][3] + 0;
                                }
                                if(richting == 5) {
                                    coordinaten[0][2] = coordinaten[0][2] + 0;
                                    coordinaten[0][3] = coordinaten[0][3] + 0;
                                }
                                if(richting == 6) {
                                    coordinaten[0][2] = coordinaten[0][2] - STAP_GROOTTE;
                                    coordinaten[0][3] = coordinaten[0][3] + 0;
                                }
                                if(richting == 7) {
                                    coordinaten[0][2] = coordinaten[0][2] + STAP_GROOTTE;
                                    coordinaten[0][3] = coordinaten[0][3] - STAP_GROOTTE;
                                }
                                if(richting == 8) {
                                    coordinaten[0][2] = coordinaten[0][2] + 0;
                                    coordinaten[0][3] = coordinaten[0][3] - STAP_GROOTTE;
                                }
                                if(richting == 9) {
                                    coordinaten[0][2] = coordinaten[0][2] - STAP_GROOTTE;
                                    coordinaten[0][3] = coordinaten[0][3] - STAP_GROOTTE;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                function randomHyperman() {
                    if(spelerMagZetten) {
                        var hyperman_x = COORDINATEN_X[Math.floor((Math.random())*AANTAL_X_COORDINATEN)];
                        var hyperman_y = COORDINATEN_Y[Math.floor((Math.random())*AANTAL_Y_COORDINATEN)];
                        for(var i=0;i<coordinaten.length;i++) {
                            if(coordinaten[i][0] == 2) {
                                if(coordinaten[i][2] == hyperman_x) {
                                    var xIsGelijk = true;
                                } else {
                                    var xIsGelijk = false;
                                }
                                if(coordinaten[i][3] == hyperman_y) {
                                    var yIsGelijk = true;
                                } else {
                                    var yIsGelijk = false;
                                }
                            }

                            if(xIsGelijk && yIsGelijk) {
                               window.requestAnimationFrame(randomHyperman);
                            } else {
                                coordinaten[0][2] = hyperman_x;
                                coordinaten[0][3] = hyperman_y;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    spelerMagZetten = false;
                }
                function randomHypermanPositie() {
                    // coordinaten[0][2] = COORDINATEN_X[Math.floor((Math.random())*AANTAL_X_COORDINATEN)];
                    // coordinaten[0][3] = COORDINATEN_Y[Math.floor((Math.random())*AANTAL_Y_COORDINATEN)];
                }

            // DROIDS
                function update() {
                    if(spelerMagZetten == false) {
                        var hyperman_x = coordinaten[0][2];
                        var hyperman_y = coordinaten[0][3];
                        for(var i=1;i<coordinaten.length;i++) {
                            if(coordinaten[i][0] == 1) {                            
                                var droid_x = coordinaten[i][2];
                                var droid_y = coordinaten[i][3];
                                if(droid_x > hyperman_x) {
                                    droid_x = droid_x - 20;
                                } else if(droid_x < hyperman_x) {
                                    droid_x = droid_x + 20;
                                }
                                if(droid_y > hyperman_y) {
                                    droid_y = droid_y - 20;
                                } else if(droid_y < hyperman_y) {
                                    droid_y = droid_y + 20;
                                }

                                coordinaten[i][2] = droid_x;
                                coordinaten[i][3] = droid_y;
                            }
                        }

                        spelerMagZetten = true;
                    }

                }
                function droidsNeerzetten() {
                    for(var i=1;i<coordinaten.length;i++) {
                        var coordinaatMaken = true;
                        while(coordinaatMaken) {
                            var droid_x = COORDINATEN_X[Math.floor((Math.random())*AANTAL_X_COORDINATEN)];
                            var droid_y = COORDINATEN_Y[Math.floor((Math.random())*AANTAL_Y_COORDINATEN)];

                            if(droid_x == coordinaten[0][2] && droid_y == coordinaten[0][3]) {
                                coordinaatMaken = true;
                            } else {
                                coordinaatMaken = false;
                                coordinaten[i][2] = droid_x;
                                coordinaten[i][3] = droid_y;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            // TEKENEN
                function draw() {  
                    // Achtergrond tekenen
                    c.fillStyle = '#f6e58d';
                    c.fillRect (0,0,CANVAS_BREEDTE,CANVAS_HOOGTE);

                    // Afbeeldingen inladen
                    var hypermanAfbeelding = new Image();
                    hypermanAfbeelding.src = 'hyperman.png';

                    var droidAfbeelding = new Image();
                    droidAfbeelding.src = 'droid.png';

                    var hoopjeAfbeelding = new Image();
                    hoopjeAfbeelding.src = 'hoopje.png';

                    // Wezens uit de array tekenen
                    for(var a=0;a<coordinaten.length;a++) {
                        if(coordinaten[a][0] == 0) {
                            c.drawImage(hypermanAfbeelding, coordinaten[a][2], coordinaten[a][3]);
                        }
                        if(coordinaten[a][0] == 1) {
                            c.drawImage(droidAfbeelding, coordinaten[a][2], coordinaten[a][3]);
                        }
                        if(coordinaten[a][0] == 2) {
                            c.drawImage(hoopjeAfbeelding, coordinaten[a][2], coordinaten[a][3]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            // OVERIGE FUNCTIES
                function botstEenDroid() {
                    var groteControle = true;
                    for(var i=1;i<coordinaten.length;i++) {
                        if(coordinaten[i][0] == 1) {
                            // Botsingen met Hyperman
                            if(coordinaten[0][2] == coordinaten[i][2] && coordinaten[0][3] == coordinaten[i][3]) {
                                gameOver();
                                groteControle = false;
                            }

                            // Botsingen met Droid
                            if(groteControle) {
                                for(var h=1;h<coordinaten.length;h++) {
                                    if(coordinaten[h][0] == 1) {
                                        if(coordinaten[h][1] != coordinaten[i][1]) {
                                            if(coordinaten[h][2] == coordinaten[i][2] && coordinaten[h][3] == coordinaten[i][3]) {
                                                coordinaten[i][0] = 2;
                                                coordinaten[h][0] = 2;
                                                score(2);
                                                console.log('Droid - Droid');
                                                console.log('---');
                                                groteControle = false;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            // Botsingen met Hoopje
                            if(groteControle) {
                                var controle = true;
                                for(var h=1;h<coordinaten.length;h++) {
                                    if(controle) {
                                        if(coordinaten[h][0] == 2) {
                                            if(coordinaten[h][2] == coordinaten[i][2] && coordinaten[h][3] == coordinaten[i][3]) {
                                                controle = false;
                                                coordinaten[i][0] = 2;
                                                score(1);
                                                console.log('Droid - Hoopje');
                                                console.log('---');
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                function score(droidsGedood) {
                    punten = punten + droidsGedood;
                    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = punten;
                }

                function gameOver() {
                    // GAME OVER
                }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're defining `coordinaten` as a local variable in the `levelUp()` function, which means it's only available in that function and not outside of it. You need to define the variable in the scope that's common to all functions using it:

```
...
            var level = 1;
            var punten = 0;
            var coordinaten;

            levelUp();

            function levelUp() {
                // Hyperman positioneren
                // Eerste getal (0, 1 of 2) = wezen (Hyperman, Droid of Hoopje); Tweede getal is het nummer (0 = ALTIJD Hyperman); Derde getal is X-coordinaat; Vierde getal is Y-coordinaat
                coordinaten = [[0,0,0,0]];
...
```

Notice how it's now defined outside of the function and simply assigned to inside the `levelUp()` function.